# VSTS pipeline similar to Jenkin's buildwithParameter?

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a Jenkins build server, which you can do "build with parameter". This is nice for the QA team, as this allows them to pick a list of features to test.

Now the business is moving everything to azure, and I am trying to move to VSTS pipeline.

On VSTS pipeline, it seems I can't just create one build pipeline, and allow people to pick a parameter and then build?

Is this feature supported in VSTS pipeline? If not, anyone got some walkaround?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is Jenkins "build with parameter" but in Azure DevOps you have an option of Variables and determine the values when you queue the build:

[image]

Add a variable and check the "Settable at queue time" checkbox:

[image]

Use the variable in the pipeline with `$(Configuration)`:

[image]

Now, when you queue the build you can choose the variable and change the value:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is quite different compared to what jenkins can do. In jenkins, you can define a list of parameters, and when do build, people can choose which parameters to use on the fly. 

For example, QA team may define 10 features and on the fly they can choose which feature to build and test.

Comment: @daxu You can achieve that with [custom conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). each feature is a task, under the tasks put the condition with a variable, when you queue the build you can determine the variable.